# Set size with unlimite value in Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I use offical php library to request ES. However, my result return max. 10 documents by query.

How to change this limit in unlimited ?

Size = 0 no work for me

Comment: hi Bastien could you mark my answer as accepted pls? every little helps! thanks! (I know its a year later but... )

Answer (score 1):

the [Elastisearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-search-type.html#scan) docs suggest a `scan` type query for a large set of results

The scan search type allows to efficiently scroll a large result set. It’s used first by executing a search request with scrolling and a query:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=10m&size=50' -d '
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all" : {}
    }
}
'
```

"The scroll parameter controls the keep alive time of the scrolling request and initiates the scrolling process. The timeout applies per round trip (i.e. between the previous scan scroll request, to the next)."